# Cannot find file 'C:\Program File\Java\jdk 1.8.0_45\jre\bin\Android'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdk-2.3, java-8

When I run Android Studio, at the beginning it show these two errors.
the Android Studio works fine, but these are just annoying. anyone knows the reason and solution?

[Cannot find file 'C:\Program File\Java\jdk 1.8.0_45\jre\bin\Android'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fab0j.jpg)

[Cannot find file 'C:\Program File\Java\jdk 1.8.0_45\jre\bin\Studio'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmX32.jpg)

Comment: what path did you set for jdk and android sdk?

Comment: jdk: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45          sdk: C:\Users\Brothers\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please **set the path of android-sdk** (you have might have set while downloading android-sdk)

**OR**

locate andoid-sdk,

In android studio , goto

**files --> project structure --> sdk location (here browse your android-sdk**)

Comment: inform me if facing any problem @Amir Ehsan Haji Hussaini